# Python: Scapy: How to read IP flags

Tags: python, ip, scapy

I am trying to figure out how to read IP flags (not TCP) using scapy library. I know it is stored in "flags" and it is FlagsField type. According to IP protocol specification there are 3 flags R, MF, and DF. I've search, and searched and could not find any info on how to read these flags. Any ideas?

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, creating an IP packet with the DF (Don't Fragment) flag set:

```
>>> packet = IP(flags=2)  # alternatively, IP(flags='DF')
>>> packet
<IP  flags=DF |>
```

Reading a packet's `flags`:

```
>>> packet.flags
2
```

As for the flag bits, Wikipedia [outlines this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) succinctly. It's a three-bit value with the following meaning:

- bit 0: Reserved; must be zero.
- bit 1: Don't Fragment (DF)
- bit 2: More Fragments (MF)

Comment: Note that the flag bits are listed from most-significant to least-significant on the Wikipedia page, so "MF" maps to 1, not 4.